# Java.Lang.Object, cannot be casted to Backed.Bean

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am creating a native query and getting result list and i want to display that in label but got the error

```
private void requestsButtonClicked() {
  try {
    String l_query = "";
    l_query = "SELECT * from tablename";
    Controller controller = new Controller(ui.getDbConnection());
    List<RequestBean> l_list = l_ric.getNativeQueryResult(l_query, RequestBean.class);
    m_requestResultNumber.setCaption(l_list.size() + "");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    m_logger.error("CATCH", e);
    org.ids.geoais.common.Process.showErrorMessage(m_RefGeoAISui, e);
  }
}
```

This is a method for native query

```
public <T> List<T> getNativeQueryResult(String p_query, Class<T> p_class) throws Exception {
  m_logger.debug("BaseController::getNativeQueryResult()");
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  m_logger.debug("SQL = " + p_query);
  List<T> l_returnList = new ArrayList<T>();
  EntityManager l_em = m_connectionInstance.getEntityManager();
  Query l_query = l_em.createNativeQuery(p_query);
  for (Object l_obj : l_query.getResultList()) {
    if (null != l_obj) {
      if (p_class.isAssignableFrom(l_obj.getClass())) {
        l_returnList.add(p_class.cast(l_obj));
      } else {
        m_logger.warn("Cannot cast the object of type " + l_obj.getClass().getName() + " to object of type " + p_class.getName());
      }
    } else {
      m_logger.warn("Search object in get query result is NULL");
    }
  }
  return l_returnList;
}
```

> Error: [2016-04-06 11:51:38,406] - WARN - (db.BaseController) - Cannot
>   cast the object of type [Ljava.lang.Object; to object of type
>   backend.bean [2016-04-06 11:51:38,406] - WARN - (db.BaseController) -
>   Cannot cast the object of type [Ljava.lang.Object; to object of type
>   backend.bean [2016-04-06 11:51:38,406] - WARN - (db.BaseController) -
>   Cannot cast the object of type [Ljava.lang.Object; to object of type
>   backend.bean

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object` is not `java.lang.Object`, it's `Object[]`. Unpack the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to omit the entity type in this call :

```
Query l_query = l_em.createNativeQuery(p_query);
```

Try with

```
Query l_query = l_em.createNativeQuery(p_query, p_class);
```

Comment: No please see in above function i am setting class name

Comment: Yes but you don't pass it to `createNativeQuery`. Could you give it a try ? Have a look at section _3.4.1.6_ here : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#query_native

Comment: Hi can you please tell me how to set parameters in this query

Comment: When i modified query                                                                         l_query = "SELECT creationdate AS " + m_dateFrom.getValue(); 
   l_query += "AND creationdate AS"  + m_dateTo.getValue(); 
   l_query += "from gaw_requestinfo";                                         It giving me the error not all named parameters have been set, how to restrict parametrs in this case?